# History of Science and Math is now in public beta

Tags: discussion, area51, stackexchange, se-sites

There is a new StackExchange site: "[History of Science and Math](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)" which has progressed into public beta.

If you are interested, take a look.

[I didn't follow the details, but it is no longer "Math and Science" but the other way around.]

Comment: We're also looking into changing the name to "History of Science and Math*ematics*", to give the term some dignity.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-math-se-seed-hsm-with-some-history-of-mathematics-questions) on HSM.

Comment: I can't suggest edits on meta, but *please* change "forum" to "Q&A site" or something along those lines. Stack Exchange is ***not*** a forum!

Comment: now called a "site"

Comment: We got a name change a couple days ago, to "History of Science and Mathematics."

Answer (score 15):

**Let me expand on this**:

At the moment the site is **very young**. This means that we need to build up a core community in running the site. MSE is one of the main "*big brothers*" of HSM so asking for some help should not be a problem. If there are any questions related to the history of Math, although they are ***still on-topic*** here, it may be worth pointing out to users that HSM does exist.

I am unsure on how much this site needs to "tap and point" users to HSM. The point of SE sites is to gather experts, teachers, learners etc. and form a community that produces good questions and answers. Now many Math experts will know their history however history of Math experts would find HSM a more suitable/logical place.

History like questions have a fundamentally different answering style to the way questions here are answered (with expectations) and I believe that HSM provides a more uniform collection of such questions and answers.

I hope many users from MSE come over to contribute as the history of mathematics is a large factor of how mathematics is done today.

Comment: It may be worthwhile noting that as per usual rules of setting up a new SE, if the two sites are in mutual agreement we can seed you guys by asking SE to migrate over a large list of our existing questions on Math History. If there is any interest in doing that our [tag:math-history] tag may be a good place to start looking.

Comment: @WillieWong This is the communities reaction [at the moment](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/116/should-math-se-seed-hsm-with-some-history-of-mathematics-questions)

Answer (score 6):

On HSM, we've been attracting some high-rep users (I won't say who) from relevant SE sites, such as Mathematics and Physics. One (from Physics) has taken an active role in shaping the site, in cases of moderation, namely, edits and close/reopen votes. It would be great if we could get some of the more experienced users on these science and math sites (don't forget Math Overflow, as well as all the other science sites on SE) to help out on HSM.

That said, we're doing fairly well even without tons of high-rep users. Most of the more active members (myself included) aren't professionals, or extremely knowledgeable experts. Most of us may not have taken courses in abstract algebra, or done research in high-energy particle physics. But we don't need to in order to comment on or moderate most of the questions. This is a new site, about a new topic, and everyone here is learning the ropes, as well as learning a lot about the world.

The gist of this answer is this: We're getting along well without a lot of experts, but they'd certainly be welcome. We've had a good first 15 days, and we'd be happy to work with anyone and everyone in order to make the next 15 (and the next 15, and the next 15) go just as well.